# JPA prevent entity from being saved

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've the following db schema:

```
account -< account_role >- role
```

Summing up: an `account` can be tied to multiple `roles` and `account_role` is a join table. `roles` is predefined and roles are inserted to DB in a migration.

Unfortunately on new `account` creating hibernate tries to insert the `role` to the table as well which results in the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "role_role_name_key"
Detail: Key (role_name)=(CUSTOMER) already exists.
```

How can I configure the relation to prevent the insertion?

Below mentioned classes:

**Role**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import static javax.persistence.EnumType.STRING;
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
class Role {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ROLE_NAME")
  @Enumerated(STRING)
  private RoleName role;
  //getters, setters, constructors
}
```

and

**Account**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "ACCOUNT_PK_SEQ", name = "ACCOUNT_PK_SEQ")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "ACCOUNT_PK_SEQ", strategy = SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "USERNAME")
  private String username;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = EAGER)
  @JoinTable(
      name = "ACCOUNT_ROLE",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USERNAME", referencedColumnName = "USERNAME"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_NAME", referencedColumnName = "ROLE_NAME")
  )
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
  //getters, setters, constructor
}
```

Here is the code responsible for saving new account:

```
@Transactional
public Account createNewAccount(Account account, String password) {
  validator.validateNewAccount(account, password);

  String email = account.getUsername().toLowerCase();

  checkIfEmailAlreadyTaken(email);

  LOG.info("Creating new account for username: '{}'.", account.getUsername());

  account.setPassword(encodePassword(password));

  account = repository.save(account);

  return account;
}
```

Object of an `Account` class is created automatically from the request.

The full exception stacktrace can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/Gkc2t80m).

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the code creating and persisting an account. Make sure you don't have a unique constraint on account_role.role_name.

Comment: @JBNizet, I've the following unique constraint: `ALTER TABLE ACCOUNT_ROLE
  ADD CONSTRAINT ACCOUNT_ROLE_UNQ UNIQUE (USERNAME, ROLE_NAME);`, stacktrace added.

Comment: You're not showing where the roles of the account come from. If they're supposed to exist, don't use new Role(roleName). Get the role by ID from the database (using findOne() or getOne())

Comment: Yes, I'm using `new`, but as you can see, `role` (enum) is and `ID` as well. Does it makes sense to fetch the roles from the DB? Hibernate can't recognize the `role` field ID?

Comment: I almost never use non-generated IDs, so I don't have much experience with that. I don't even understand why Hibernate is trying to save the roles, since you don't have any cascade annotation on the association. But my rule of thumb is that you should avoid detached objects like the plague, and that, if a row exists in the database, then you should get the corresponding managed entity from JPA instead of representing it with a (or several different) detached objects.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks! You've never used dictionary table without generated key?

Comment: I must have done that once or twice. But if the table contains several columns, I can't guess all their value and thus can't create an instance from scratch, so I need to get it from the database. And if it just contains one column of type enum, then I can just store the enum directly in then entity, rather than storing a reference to an entity which contains an enum.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by

```
@Id
@Column(name = "ROLE_NAME")
@Enumerated(STRING)
```

The JPA spec says :

> 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> The primary key (or field or property of a composite primary key) should be one of the following types: any Java primitive type; any primitive wrapper type; java.lang.String; java.util.Date; java.sql.Date. In general, however, approximate numeric types (e.g., floating point types) should never be used in primary keys. Entities whose primary keys use types other than these will not be portable.

So the combination of @Id and @Enumeration seems not allowed as you are using an enum as id.

With your current code you can write only as many roles as the enum RoleName has elements. These are the predifined roles of your system.
You should do that once on startup (or otherwise make sure they exist)

Add the annotation

```
@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
```

to Account.roles, this tells the JPA provider, to not insert or update the roles, when an Account is inserted or updated.

This should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response and deep analysis. I suppose it would work, however I've changed the DB design and can't verify it :/